# Unable to print data for last 6 months in SQL with Subquery

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to get result for the last 6 months from a set of data, however when I run my query it shows nothing. The question I'm working on is:

Q. *Using a subquery, print name, cost and the maximum distance of the transport if the transport has been allocated (use the start date of the allocation here) within the last 6 months calculated from today
(Today here implies the date the query is run. Must not hardcode the date)*

This is my query:

```
SELECT TransportCost, TransportName, TransportMaxDist
FROM Service
WHERE FromDate IN
(SELECT FromDate
FROM Service
WHERE MONTH(FromDate) = 6);
```

When I run this query it shows the correct column names, but there is no data in those columns:

```
+---------------+---------------+------------------+
| TransportCost | TransportName | TransportMaxDist |
+---------------+---------------+------------------+
|               |               |                  |
+---------------+---------------+------------------+
```

Below are the `CREATE TABLE` and sample data syntaxes:

```
CREATE TABLE Allocation (
  TruckVINNum CHAR (4),
  TransportID CHAR (2),
  FromDate CHAR (16),
  ToDate CHAR (16),
  TruckAllocation CHAR (8),
  PRIMARY KEY (TruckVINNum, TransportID)
);

INSERT INTO Allocation VALUES
    ('VO23','T1','2020-12-05','2020-12-08','3 Days'),
    ('VO24','T2','2020-12-03','2020-12-07','4 Days'),
    ('VO25','T3','2020-12-07','2020-12-13','6 Days'),
    ('VO26','T4','2021-09-01','2021-09-10','9 Days'),
    ('VO27','T5','2021-07-16','2021-07-21','5 Days');

CREATE TABLE Service(
    TransportID CHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY,
    TransportName VARCHAR(11),
    TransportCost DECIMAL(6,2),
    TransportMaxDist DECIMAL(6,2),
    FromDate CHAR(16)
);

INSERT INTO Service VALUES
    ('T1','Removalist',5000.50, 1000.56,'2020-12-05'),
    ('T2','Carpenter',1500.00, 550.18, '2020-12-03'),
    ('T3','Electrician',1750.50, 988.00,'2020-12-07'),
    ('T4','Scaffolder',2400.70, 340.76,'2021-09-10'),
    ('T5','Plumber',2100.00, 668.90,'2021-07-16');
```

Comment: You don't have any dates where the month is 6. `FromDate > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)` for the date part of the expression. It would help if you used `Allocation` in your query.

Comment: Sorry what would the whole query look like? I'm a bit confused as where to put the FromDate query.

Comment: What would be the correct result?

Comment: Why are all of your date columns CHAR instead of DATE? If they're dates they should be stored as DATEs, not something else. You're making your life a thousand times more difficult by not using the proper data type.

Comment: Ohhhh makes sense, I'll fix that first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to know what is your query doing, particularly the subquery. Let's inspect your query here:

```
SELECT TransportCost, TransportName, TransportMaxDist
FROM Service
WHERE FromDate IN
/*the query inside the parentheses is called as subquery*/
(SELECT FromDate
FROM Service
WHERE MONTH(FromDate) = 6);
```

When you run that subquery alone, you're doing `WHERE MONTH(FromDate) = 6` which means that you'll only want a data where the month value in `FromDate` column is `6` or `June`; regardless of year and day. That's not really fulfilling the condition of *"... within the last 6 months calculated from today..."*.

For "within 6 month" condition, you need to use MySQL date manipulation functions like  [DATE INTERVAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) and [CURDATE() or CURRENT_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) functions. Therefore, a query like this:

```
SELECT TransportCost, TransportName, TransportMaxDist, FromDate
FROM Service
WHERE FromDate >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 6 MONTH);
```

As you can see, the operation `DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 6 MONTH)` takes `CURDATE()` which is today, subtract it by 6 month interval using `DATE_SUB()`. This can also be written like:

```
SELECT TransportCost, TransportName, TransportMaxDist, FromDate
FROM Service
WHERE FromDate >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH);
```

I think you'll understand more what that function do when you run `SELECT CURDATE() AS 'Today', DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AS '6 Months Ago from Today'`.

One particular detail mentioned by @KenWhite in the comment is about the `FromDate`(in both tables) and `ToDate` column datatype. Which in your example is `CHAR` instead of `DATE`. The possible problem with this is that you might get incorrect/inconsistent results when using date manipulation functions. There is a way to convert that data into a recognizable date format but it'll make the query longer than necessary. So, if it's suppose to store date, then use the proper `DATE` datatype for the columns.

Here's a [demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=202a6092787ec6c695aad686b41e7a1a).

Comment: Oh okay it makes sense now. I ran into a problem with inserting null values into my data after changing from char to date but I've fixed that now, thank you!